# Install TWRP on Samsung Note 10.1

Tags: adb, samsung, fastboot, twrp, samsung-galaxy-note-10.1

I am following [this guide from Cyanogenmods](http://www.cyanogenmods.org/forums/topic/install-twrp-recovery-android-using-fastboot/) to install TWRP on a Samsung Note 10.1 with Android 5.1.1 installed. I have activated *USB Debugging* in *Developer options* and connected the tablet to my computer, accepting the connection in the dialogue that pops up in the tablet. I then issue the `adb` command:

```
$ adb reboot bootloader
```

There is no error message, either on the computer or the tablet, and the tablet reboots.

I then issue the *flash* command:

```
$ fastboot flash twrp-3.0.2-0-lt03wifiue.img
< waiting for device >
```

And nothing else happens. The tablet remains silent and the command line in my computer is stuck. How do I move on from here?

**Update I**: This is the system and software in my computer:

```
$ uname -a
Linux ENG-PAVIL-PC2 4.4.0-87-generic #110-Ubuntu SMP Tue Jul 18 12:55:35 UTC 2017 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

$ apt policy adb
adb:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 1:6.0.1+r16-3
  Version table:
     1:6.0.1+r16-3 500
        500 http://ch.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/universe amd64 Packages

$ apt policy fastboot
fastboot:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 1:6.0.1+r16-3
  Version table:
     1:6.0.1+r16-3 500
        500 http://ch.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/universe amd64 Packages
```

**Update II**: The bootloader version on this tablet is: P600XXUDQA1

**Update III**: `heimdall` was referenced below as an alternative to `fastboot`, but it is not able to communicate with the Samsung Note 10.1:

```
$ heimdall flash --no-reboot --RECOVERY twrp-3.0.2-0-lt03wifiue.img
Heimdall v1.4.1

Copyright (c) 2010-2014 Benjamin Dobell, Glass Echidna
http://www.glassechidna.com.au/

This software is provided free of charge. Copying and redistribution is
encouraged.

If you appreciate this software and you would like to support future
development please consider donating:
http://www.glassechidna.com.au/donate/

Initialising connection...
Detecting device...
ERROR: Failed to detect compatible download-mode device.

$ adb devices
List of devices attached 
4300ee259691c037    device
```

**Update IV**: Still trying it out with `heimdall`, which so far is the only tool providing any bit of hope. For some reason it sometimes fails to identify Download mode - that is the reason for the error messages in Update III. By plugging in/out the USB cable and using the `detect` option one can eventually make sure it acquired the device:

```
$ heimdall detect
Device detected
```

Then the `flash` command succeeds:

```
$ heimdall flash --no-reboot --RECOVERY twrp-3.0.2-0-lt03wifiue.img
Heimdall v1.4.1

Copyright (c) 2010-2014 Benjamin Dobell, Glass Echidna
http://www.glassechidna.com.au/

This software is provided free of charge. Copying and redistribution is
encouraged.

If you appreciate this software and you would like to support future
development please consider donating:
http://www.glassechidna.com.au/donate/

Initialising connection...
Detecting device...
Claiming interface...
Setting up interface...

Initialising protocol...
Protocol initialisation successful.

Beginning session...

Some devices may take up to 2 minutes to respond.
Please be patient!

Session begun.

Downloading device's PIT file...
PIT file download successful.

Uploading RECOVERY
100%
RECOVERY upload successful

Ending session...
Releasing device interface...
```

Now things get tricky. If the tablet is rebooted normally after TWRP is flashed, the stock bootloader (I believe) will replace it automatically. In this case when the tablet is rebooted into recovery mode it will just run the stock Android recovery programme. It took me a while to figure this one out...

After flashing TWRP, the tablet must be rebooted directly into recovery mode. The problem is, it shows an error in the booting screen:

> Could not do normal boot. Invalid KERNEL LENGTH!

TWRP does not load and the tablet just shuts down. That is how far I am right now.

Comment: That "for any Android" guide is junk, my friend. Samsung devices do not have `fastboot`, as Samsung uses their `Odin` software to flash firmwares and recoveries.

Comment: @beeshyams Actually, it's not ideal for me to provide an answer, as I do lack access to any modern Samsung device, and, given the added complications introduced by S (e.g. locked bootloaders), I'm not the best one to provide an answer concerning those devices.

Comment: It has Android 5.1.1 (question updated). Where can I check the boot loader details?

Comment: Boot loader version is P600XXUDQA1 (I'll update the question). But I could not find any information on that carrier lock setting (at least not in Phone Info Samsung).

Comment: I'm seeing your edit to the question. This is weird... I've never seen that boot-time error before, despite having flashed tens of Samsung devices. Is it simply impossible to reach for a Windows PC and try Odin at the moment?

Comment: I understand you wish to help, but your promotion of Windows is going a bit too far, I think. I do not own a licence to that system and do not intend to buy one.

Comment: Revisited this question after seeing your latest question - in your last edit after Heimdall, you could try the [hardware key combination](http://www.tomsguide.com/forum/id-2079689/factory-reset-samsung-galaxy-note.html) to boot into recovery. If you get into TWRP now, from TWRP options reboot into system !

Comment: When I try to boot into recovery as you say I get the message in question: *Could not do normal boot. Invalid KERNEL LENGTH!*

Comment: Ahh, my misunderstanding that this was Linux based boring into recovery and thought that hardware key combo may overriding this

Comment: @LuísdeSousa Sadly, it's not a matter of advertising, as many users of this site are quite privacy-minded. It's just a matter of acknowledging that Odin works, while Heimdall fails. Did you already try to run Odin via Wine?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note 10.1 (2014) has its bootloader unlocked by default, just like most if not all devices annouced pre-Lollipop.

Under Windows, the actual installation is as simple as described in the [TWRP device page](https://twrp.me/devices/samsunggalaxynote1012014exynos.html):

> You will need to download and install Odin on your PC. Once you have Odin installed, download the proper .tar file for your device from the download link above. Power off your device. Turn on your device using the proper key combo to get into download mode and attach the device to your computer via a USB cable. Use the PDA tab or button to browse to and select the tar file that you downloaded and flash the device.

Under Linux, Heimdall is required instead, and steps are somewhat different: download the `.img` file, get into download mode, (optionally) verify connection with `heimdall detect`, then execute `heimdall flash --no-reboot --RECOVERY /path/to/recovery.img` to flash it to the device.

Do note that there are multiple, *very* different variants of this device. The WiFi version (P600) and LTE version (P605) are based on different SoCs and therefore use different recoveries and ROMs, while the Verizon variant (P605V) has a locked (and non-unlockable) bootloader which means you can't flash anything on it.

Comment: "download and install Odin on your PC" I would need the details on this bit to follow your suggestion.

Comment: For Windows machines, get Odin [here](http://dl.sammobile.com/Odin3-v3.12.7.zip). Just extract it somewhere and run the main executable. As for Linux, [Heimdall](http://glassechidna.com.au/heimdall/) is the one to use. I personally always go for Odin (even though I have a Ubuntu environment) due to Heimdall being a command-line tool.

Comment: Neither the Heimdall frontend nor its command line are able to connect to the tablet. Apparently this programme does not support the Samsung Note 10.1. Please clarify further your answer, as it is it is not really helpful.

Comment: Heimdall is *supposed* to support future Samsung devices up till now. I still advise finding a Windows PC for the job though, as Odin is an official tool of Samsung, and the GUI will prevent confusion. I will modify my answer as we work to make clear what route you take.

Comment: Also, I can't quite remember if one could use `adb reboot bootloader` to get to Download Mode. From the response of your terminal, it simply seems you're not even in Download Mode yet. When you issue that command, do you see some lines of text on the left-up corner of the screen, or a green Android bot in the middle? If neither, then you're definitely not ready. The *right* way is to power off the device completely, hold VOL_DOWN and HOME then hold POWER, until it shows a warning. Then press VOL_UP to confirm.

Comment: Considering that `heimdall` itself was reporting a successful flashing process, I decided to investigate this further using other images. As it turns out, the SM-P600 boots correctly into recovery mode with TWRP 2.8.7 and 3.0.1. There was either an issue with the `.img` file or that latest TWRP version is struggling wih the SM-P600. Since it was you that directed me to `heimdall` I would like to accept your answer. Please update it with a link to the tool and an example (you can use the command in Update III).

Comment: Glad you got it in the end. It still appears weird to me that the latest image fails - it's quite dated so if it's problematic then people would've reported and the maintainer would've gotten it replaced. Might want to double-check the hash?